# Error: Could not find or load main class weblogic.management.commo.WebLogicMBeanMaker in Oracle WebLogic Server 12.1.2.0.0

Tags: java, weblogic12c

Where I could find the find the class **weblogic.management.commo.WebLogicMBeanMaker** ?????

I thought it was in the file **weblogic.jar**, but the file ony has 1 KB, but there are others like **weblogic-ja.jar** with 515 KB, **weblogic-de.jar** WITH 50 KB, etc, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding weblogic.jar to the CLASSPATH worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

rather added the weblogic.jar location as -lib

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this  may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. 
 Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)